# Is this thread-safe with concurrent access?

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

I have struct with `count` property need to thread-safe access.

I know it can be done with `sync.Mutex` or `sync.RWMutex`. But I am not sure it's ok like this:

```
type Status struct {
    count uint32

    attr1 string
    attr2 string
}

func (s *Status) Get() uint32 {
    return atomic.LoadUint32(&s.count)
}

func (s *Status) Add(n uint32) {
    atomic.AddUint32(&s.count, n)
}

func (s *Status) Reset(n uint32) {
    atomic.StoreUint32(&s.count, n)
}
```

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I'm confused that access field directly `s.count` is not safe. But `atomic.LoadUint32(&s.count)` is safe?

Comment: Accessing any field in any language is unsafe - except maybe some pure functional languages like Erlang and Elixir or Haskell or some languages that have complex type systems that consider concurrency as part of their type system Like Pony or some languages like Rust that "provide" means to make concurrent access safe. So you should always consider pretty much everything concurrent-unsafe when using usual/mainstream programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if only those 3 methods access the `count` field, your solution is safe to use concurrently from multiple goroutines.

But know that the value returned by `Status.Get()` may be "outdated" by the time you attempt to use it. E.g.:

```
s := &Status{}

if s.Get() == 3 {
    fmt.Println(s.Get()) // This may or may not print 3
}

// Or
c := s.Get()
fmt.Println(c == s.Get()) // This may or may not print true
```

The above example may or may not print `3` and `true` as the 2nd call to `s.Get()` might be preceeded by another call to `s.Add()` in another goroutine.

If you need guarantee that noone else modifies or accesses the value of the `Status.count` field while you perform further calculations on it, then [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) or [`sync.RWMutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) is the way to go, as you can hold a lock on the `count` field while you finish your calculations.

**Edit:** To answer your edit:

Direct access to `s.count` is not safe, `atomic.LoadUint32(&s.count)` is safe. Reason for this is because if goroutine #1 calls `s.Add()`, and goroutine #2 tries to access `s.count`, there is no guarantee that goroutine #2 will see changes made by #1. In #2 you may see just a cached version of `s.count`.

Without explicit synchronization you have no guarantee to observe changes made to a variable in another goroutine. Directly accessing `s.count` is an unsynchronized access. Use of channels or other synchronization primitives (e.g. [`sync`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) or [`sync/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) packages) ensures serialized access to `s.count`, so these solutions will always see the current, updated value.

For details, see this article: [**The Go Memory Model**](https://golang.org/ref/mem)